# Redirect a route path in Apache 2.4 except my IP

Tags: .htaccess, apache2.4

I try to redirect all visit except from my own IP adress to a specific path/url (not file or directory just a route path)like "example.com/my-path" to home page. I have tried a several code in .htaccess file but nothing works.

I used this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} != 1.2.3.4 (MY IP) 
RewriteRule /my-path https://example.com
```

Where I have wrong?

Comment: When configured in .htaccess, the path RewriteRule matches against _never_ starts with a leading slash, that has been stripped off at this point already.

Comment: (And you should anchor that pattern at the start and end, if you don't want it to match on paths that just _contain_ `my-path` anywhere.)

Comment: I have tested- RewriteRule "/my-path" "https://example.com" - and - RewriteRule "/my-path" https://example.com - but not works.

Comment: And what did I tell you about the leading slash, in my first comment?

Comment: Tried - RewriteRule ^/my-path$ https://example.com [R=302,NC] - still nothing

Comment: _Still_ a leading slash in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} != 1.2.3.4 (MY IP) 
> RewriteRule /my-path https://example.com
> ```

There's a few errors here:

- There should be no space after `!=` and before the string you are testing. `!=` is part of the *CondPattern* (2nd argument). `=` is a prefix-operator (that makes it a string match, instead of a regex) and `!` is an additional operator that negates the expression. So `!=` is not one operator, but two stuck together.
- The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `/my-path`) is a regex that matches the requested URL-path. Note, however, that in a *directory* context (eg. `.htaccess`), the URL-path that is matched does not start with a slash.
- This will implicitly trigger a 302 (temporary) redirect. However, you should always be explicit and include the `R` flag.
- For external redirects you should nearly always include the `L` (`last`) flag to prevent further processing.

The above should be written like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.4
RewriteRule ^my-path$ https://example.com/ [R=302,L]
```

This will match the requested URL `/my-path` and issue a temporary redirect to `https://example.com/` if the request is coming from an IP address that is not `1.2.3.4`.